# Send video between UWP and Unity

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, tcp, uwp

I'm struggling on a big project and I need help.

To give you the context. I have a video feed coming in a UWP (from the DJI SDK) and I try to get this video in Unity. I tried really a lot of things (simulate webcam, NamedPipes, UDP) and currently I think the best solution is TCP.

So I built a TCP server in my UWP and I try to send the byte[] from the video to the TCP client in Unity.

But I can't establish the connection between the 2 applications. After a minute I just got a SocketException saying that the server never respond

Here is the UWP code :

```
private Parser vp;
    private const string PORT = "1337";
    private StreamWriter TCP_client_stream = null;

    public MainPage() {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.StartServer();

        DJISDKManager.Instance.SDKRegistrationStateChanged += Instance_SDKRegistrationEvent;

        DJISDKManager.Instance.RegisterApp("29f7d391513c4052daef008d");
    }

    //######### DJI #########
    private async void Instance_SDKRegistrationEvent(SDKRegistrationState state, SDKError resultCode) {
        if (resultCode == SDKError.NO_ERROR) {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Register app successfully");
            if (vp == null) {
                vp = new Parser();
                vp.Initialize(delegate (byte[] data) {
                    return DJISDKManager.Instance.VideoFeeder.ParseAssitantDecodingInfo(0, data);
                });

                vp.SetSurfaceAndVideoCallback(0, 0, null, ReceiveDeocodedData);
                DJISDKManager.Instance.VideoFeeder.GetPrimaryVideoFeed(0).VideoDataUpdated += OnVideoPush;
            }
            //DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetFlightControllerHandler(0, 0).AttitudeChanged += OnAttitudUpdate;
            DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetCameraHandler(0, 0).CameraTypeChanged += OnCameraTypeChanged;//On ajoute nos fonctions a ce qui se fait deja
            var type = await DJISDKManager.Instance.ComponentManager.GetCameraHandler(0, 0).GetCameraTypeAsync();
            OnCameraTypeChanged(this, type.value);
        } else {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Register SDK failed : ");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(resultCode.ToString());
        }
    }

    //######### TCP #########
    private void StartServer() {
        try {
            var streamSocketListener = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener();
            
            streamSocketListener.ConnectionReceived += this.StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived;
            streamSocketListener.BindServiceNameAsync(PORT);

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("server is listening...");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketErrorStatus webErrorStatus = Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketError.GetStatus(e.GetBaseException().HResult);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(webErrorStatus.ToString() != "Unknown" ? webErrorStatus.ToString() : e.Message);
        }
    }

    //On va recylcer ca pour que ca devienne un outil pour fermer
    private async void StreamSocketListener_ConnectionReceived(Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener sender, Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args) {
        string request;
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead())) {
            request = await streamReader.ReadLineAsync();
        }

        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("server received the request: \"{0}\"", request)));

        // Echo the request back as the response.
        TCP_client_stream = new StreamWriter(args.Socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TCP connected");
        using (Stream outputStream = args.Socket.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite()) {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(outputStream)) {
                await streamWriter.WriteLineAsync(request);
                await streamWriter.FlushAsync();
            }
        }

        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("server sent back the response: \"{0}\"", request)));

        sender.Dispose();

        await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("server closed its socket"));
    }
```

The error seem to come from vp.SetSurfaceAndVideoCallback(0, 0, null, ReceiveDeocodedData); because when I remove it, it works

I tried to call that from a dispatcher but nothing changed

The unity code :

```
void Start() {
    ConnectToTcpServer();
    SendMessage();
}

void Update() {
}

private void ConnectToTcpServer() {
    try {
        Debug.Log("Start thread");
        clientReceiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForData));
        clientReceiveThread.IsBackground = true;
        clientReceiveThread.Start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.Log("On client connect exception " + e);
    }
}

private void ListenForData() {
    try {
        Debug.Log("Try to connect");
        socketConnection = new TcpClient("192.168.1.27", PORT);
        Debug.Log("Connected");
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[videoFrameSize];
        while (true) {
            // Get a stream object for reading              
            using (NetworkStream stream = socketConnection.GetStream()) {
                int length;
                // Read incoming stream into byte arrary.                   
                while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0) {
                    //
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException socketException) {
        Debug.Log("Socket exception: " + socketException);
    }
}
```

If you have some idea to solve that or another approach to send this video it would be very nice of you. I'm turning crazy on this problem

Comment: You mention an error.. What error? you should be able to tell if the connection is made, is it? is it a case of just the data isnt being sent / received as expected?

Comment: No no the connection is never made. I just got after 1 min a SocketException saying that server never respond

Comment: well, are you sure the app with the listener is running and working? have you connected to it using something else?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, when I remove the line the connection works

Comment: I've answered this question before.  The code is missing the Listener Start method!!!.